# Dynamically populate react-router-dom's Route elements

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a json file that contains the following information.

```
"id": "1",
"name": "Home",
"url": "/",
"component": "Home.js"
```

Using the information in the json file I want to populate the routing for my react webpage.
I am trying to do this all dynamically. I am stuck on how to configure the `element` in the `react-rounter-dom`.

I thought that I could `lazy` to import the webpages and set the `element` to that but I think that because element requires a react component not an imported file it doesnt work.

Here are the relevant parts of my code.

Lazy loading the webpages

```
const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const addPage = () => {
      const newPage = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        newPage.push(lazy(() => import(`./pages/${menuItems.pages[i].component}`)));
      }
      setPages(newPage);
    };  

    addPage();

  }, [menuItems])
```

The Route code

```
menuItems.pages.map((menuItem, index) => (
            <Routes>              
                <Route
                  key={index}                
                  path={menuItem.url}
                  component={pages[index]}
                />              
            </Routes>
          ))
```

Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, I was being a bit silly. The crux of the issue was not checking to ensure that the `pages` variable had been populated. I also found that I should set `page` rather than trying to set `pages[index]` in elements.

```
<Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        {menuItems.pages && menuItems.pages.length > 0 && <Navbar menuItems={menuItems} />}
        <Routes>
          {menuItems.pages && menuItems.pages.length > 0 && pages && pages.length > 0 &&
            menuItems.pages.map((menuItem, index) => {
              const Page = pages[index];
              return (
                <Route
                  key={menuItem.id}
                  path={menuItem.url}
                  element={<Page />} 
                />
            );
          })}
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
```